# JMeter - Why is my variable being re-evaluated midway through my test?

Tags: jmeter

I posted this question originally in a much more complicated way, but I've reproduced the issue more simply now so I'm extensively editing my post.

I have a simple Test Plan to exercise an API.

[image: Test Plan tree]

The first thing it does is create a session with a simple `HTTP POST`. We then extract the session ID from the response using the `JSON Path Extractor` plugin:

[image: JSON Path Extractor]

This reads the newly created session's ID into a variable called `id_JSON`, and subsequent `PUT` requests use the session ID in their path, i.e. `/api/sessions/${id_JSON}/account`.

This generally works well, but I have noticed that intermittently, `id_JSON` will suddenly have the default value `NOT_FOUND`. Samples will fail and when I look at the request, I can see that it was trying to hit `/api/sessions/NOT_FOUND/account` instead of a valid ID. What's really confusing me right now is that this will happen after requests have already successfully referenced `${id_JSON}` and generated a valid path. It seems like this should be impossible, unless the value of `id_JSON` was being dynamically checked or looked up repeatedly - otherwise how is it coming up with a different value from one request to the next?

It seems that if any Sample fails, for any reason, subsequent requests in the same thread iteration all fail with `id_JSON` having the default value `NOT_FOUND`.

Do I need to declare or manage the variable `id_JSON` in any special way to ensure that it will get the value of the session ID and retain it throughout the thread iteration, until the next iteration overwrites it with the next session ID?

Comment: can you show your test plan structure ?

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK: Yes, I'll throw something up, though if you can point me to another question on here where a user posted the info you're looking for, it would be helpful to see that and use it as a template.

Comment: a screenShot highligting the extractor, where you extract and the loopcontroller is enough

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK: Added screenshots and explanations. Thanks!

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK: I found a much simpler way to reproduce the issue, so I've rewritten my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Extractor is a [Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), meaning it is applied after each sampler. So in you case it will run on the First Get and the 4 Puts.

So what you are noticing is absolutely regular, and if a Sampler fails, the extractor will fail to extract the ID and put NOT_FOUND in value.

If you are sure it does not change, then just put the Post Processor as a child of the first HTTP Request called "Create Session", it will then only run for it and the variable will not change anymore.

You can read more on this at:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules

Comment: Thanks! Once I started using a default value and seeing that it was being re-evaluated, I knew there had to be something simple that I was missing.

I've built it into my test and am testing now - having some server issues that are making it harder to confirm. But once I do a little more testing to confirm that I'm set, the bounty is yours! :) Also, thanks for that scoping reference. Looks like something I definitely need to read up on.

Answer (score 0):

"Go to next loop iteration" operates on Thread Group level.

Using any nested loop controllers doesn't increment global iteration counter. You can test it with either:

- [${__BeanShell(vars.getIteration();)}](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) function - if you use vanilla JMeter
- [iterationNum](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) function - if you use [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)

So if you move your "looping" on Thread Group level and remove nester Loop Controller(s) (or set their loop count to 1) your approach should work as you expect it to do.

Comment: I'm confused. I don't think I have any nested loop controllers. There is only one `Loop Controller` in my test plan, and it's the `Loop on ___ Status` controller. The `End loop on error` controller is an `If Controller`, and the `Single Flow` controller is a `Simple Controller`.

When I use `Go to next loop iteration` I want it to move on to the next iteration at the thread level - to start from the beginning, create a new session, get a new session ID, etc. So I kind of think it is doing what I want it to do.

I'm not sure how your answer relates to the `id_JSON` variable getting set to null.